# JFrame button exception

Tags: java, button, exception, jframe

I'm making a project, it's a bookstore and one of it's functionalities is that when you select a book you can add it in a cart. What I want is when no book is selected I want it to pop out a window saying that no book is selected. How do I do this?

my code looks like this:

```
    int selectedRow = tabBook.getSelectedRow();

    int selectedModelIndex = tabBook.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRow);

    selectedBook = bookTableModel.giveBookByRowNumber(selectedModelIndex);

    if(isCart == false){
        cartForm = new Cart(selectedBook, this);
        cartForm.setVisible(true);
        isCart = true;
    } else {
        cartForm.addSelectedBook(selectedBook);
        cartForm.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tabBook.getSelectedRow();` will return `-1` if no row is selected. So you can do something like this:

```
int selectedRow = tabBook.getSelectedRow();
if (selectedRow < 0){
    javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select a book!", "Error!", javax.swing.JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    return; /* Exit your function */
}
```

Comment: @sathariel: if this answer helped you, you can *accept* it for others' reference.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your program looks like.. How are the books that one can buy presented? In a table?

If it is so, you can do something like:

if the number of selected items in the table == 0
    show Dialog "No book selected"